# Why do certain countries no display on world Map?

Tags: jvectormap

Why don't certain countries appear on the world map?

- Tonga
- Cook Islands
- Somoa
- Tahiti

Is there a way to modify the world map so that these countries do display?

Answer (score 0):

Because they are too small to be properly represented on the world map. Take a look at this [demo](http://jvectormap.com/examples/markers-world/).